# C# insert query - no return value from ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

Can you help me out with this? My code seems to be fine but there are no return value from `ExecuteNonQuery`. see my code below:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn;
    conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbsCOLLABERA.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

    string sqlAdd = "insert into tblEmployeeList(empID,empLName,empFName,empMName,empGender,empBDate,empAddress,empEAddress,empPNumber,empPosition,empStatus,empHRate,empOTRate,empTimeIn,empTimeOut) values ('"
  + txtID.Text + "','" + txtLName.Text + "','" + txtFName.Text + "','" + txtMName.Text + "','" + txtGender.SelectedValue + "','" + txtBDate.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtEAddress.Text + "','" + txtPNumber.Text + "','" + txtPosition.Text + "','"
   + txtStatus.SelectedValue + "'," + txtHRate.Text + "," + txtOTRate.Text + ",'" + txtTimeIn.SelectedValue + "','" + txtTimeOut.SelectedValue + "')";

    OleDbCommand cmdAdd = new OleDbCommand(sqlAdd, conn);

    conn.Open();
    cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //oledbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(sqlAdd);
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting as a return value? An INSERT-Statement doesn't return anything. :)

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks, you really should use parameterized queries.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are expecting to be returned... and what the issue is because you are right, your code does look fine as it...

Comment: @user743414: It does. Hence the `int` return type of that method.

Comment: `For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.` ... so what are you expecting here?

Comment: Is not related to your question, but if you use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx your code will be more clear

Comment: it does not show any error bit it does not insert any values to the table.

Comment: @mpacheco nope the proper way to make this more clear is to use parameters

Comment: @iamkrillin well then the proper way would be then use some kind of framework to handle basic things like inserts, updates and deletes

Comment: @mpacheco I don't disagree with that, but advising to use string.format() to fix sql queries is kinda like saying dont play with bombs, but play with guns instead.  Both methods will end in pain and destruction

Comment: @iamkrillin it was just a suggestion to make more readable his current code...

Comment: Agree with @iamkrillin. Parameters is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

It should return the number of lines affected, in this case 1. Try assign the result:

```
int rowsAffected = cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

Use this code:

```
string sqlAdd = "insert into tblEmployeeList(empID,empLName,empFName,empMName,empGender,empBDate,empAddress,empEAddress,empPNumber,empPosition,empStatus,empHRate,empOTRate,empTimeIn,empTimeOut) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtID.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtLName.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtFName.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtMName.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtGender.SelectedValue);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtBDate.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtAddress.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtEAddress.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtPNumber.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtPosition.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtStatus.SelectedValue);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtHRate.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtOTRate.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtTimeIn.SelectedValue);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtTimeOut.SelectedValue);
```

This fixes your SQL injection vulnerabilities, uses parameters to pass the parameters, no need to construct the SQL yourself. And ODBC uses `?` for parameter, since it doesn't support parameters.

Comment: it does not show any error bit it does not insert any values to the table

Comment: What is the value for `rowsAffected` if you run this? Are you sure there is no exception? Try to set a `try...catch` around it.

Comment: nothing shows and nothings happens. It's working fine but of no insertion of the data to the table.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions.

Comment: Mh ok. I've used that method for long time, on another object SqlCommand, but I've never looked or used the return value.

Comment: it encountered an error: Argument 1: cannot convert from int to string

Comment: that's your answer then. One of your fields it expecting an int value and you're sending it text. Convert it before 'adding'. This can easily be solved by using parameters. (BTW it's probably your ID field, amongst possibly others)

Comment: As an improvement you could remove empid from your insert statement and make it autoincrement in access.

Comment: @user743414 not necessarily. It depends on what the OP is doing to the data. They may want the ID to be shown to the user.

Comment: @CaptainBadass: I am feeling helpful today ;) . Use the code in the answer. It fixes your SQL injection vulnerabilities, uses parameters to pass the parameters, to no need to make the SQL yourself. And ODBC uses `?` for parameter, since it doesn't support parameters.